# How to get GPS coordinates from Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, gps

When I watch it on the internet, the code in the image proceeds without error when run, but it gives me such an output. What could be the reason for this?
I am using Raspberry Pi 3B+ model.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and share other details (such as the model information of the devices used, a repeatable example of the code you tried, error code as text).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do not show pictures of text. Copy and paste the text as text.